# why does filter_input() return NULL when I manually assign value to $_POST array?

Tags: php, filter, validation

I'm following some exercises about data validation and decided to mess around with the `filter_input()` function. When I try to run this code:

```
$_POST['var'] = 10;

$filtered = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

var_dump($filtered);
```

`var_dump($filtered)` returns NULL. I know the code works if `$_POST['var']` is assigned a value by submitting a form, but I'm just wondering why manually assigning a value to the `$_POST[]` array doesn't return `float(10)`?

Comment: 7 years going, and PHP still hasn't fixed this bug with `filter_input()`.  So, I end up doing `filter_var(@$_POST['var'])` to silence the `Undefined index: var` PHP notice if it's unset, which `filter_input()` handles for you.  Disappointing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`filter_input()` doesn't read from the _POST/_GET/_COOKIE/_SERVER/_ENV superglobal arrays. It reads from the original sources of those values respectively (which are also used to populate the superglobals).

Comment: Can I access the original sources directly?

Comment: @user If you want to use `INPUT_POST`, it specifically validates *the POSTed data*. If you want to validate other data that you have set, don't use `INPUT_POST`.

Comment: @deceze What about XMLHttpRequests via POST? Those data were also "_POSTed_" (smh), but the filter_input method can't find the data. Why is that?

Comment: @doABarrelRoll721 Did you post JSON by any chance?

Comment: @deceze `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', .....` But never mind. I figured it out. I'm using filter_var instead now.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `INPUT_POST` works on the original POST values, modifications to them in your script have no effect.
However, if you want to filter that var you can use:

```
filter_var($_POST['var'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a default input value and filter, use `filter_var`. Because filter_input doesn't filter current values of superglobals.